# Transparent navigation menu that pushes content down

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, navigation, navbar

I am looking for the best way of making a transparent navigation bar that pushes other div's under it.

The way I achieve the transparent navbar right now, is by giving it position: absolute. But this makes the next div on the page go on top of it/behind it.

EDIT:

I'm working in Ruby on Rails 5.2.0 RC1 and using bootstrap 4.

This is what's inside my body tag in my application.html.erb:

```
<body>
<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>

<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">

        <%= link_to root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' do %>
          <%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>
        <% end %>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Bonnets', products_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'About', about_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <%= link_to 'Contact', new_message_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown d-sm-none d-md-block">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-no">
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-3x side-item"></i>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Checkout</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



<%= yield %>

<footer>
  <div class="inner-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-inline payment-icons justify-content-center">
        <i class="fab fa-cc-visa fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-stripe fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-paypal fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Bonnets', products_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'About', about_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to 'Contact', new_message_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="d-flex copyright justify-content-center">
        <p>Copyright <%= Date.today.year %> © <strong>Muli Clothing</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

This is the relevant css for the navbar:

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And this is the code for my homepage:

```
<div class="container-fluid home banner">
    <div class="text-box">
      <div class="text-box-inner">
        <h1 class="uppercase">The better to clothe you with, my dear</h1>
        <button class="btn"><%= link_to 'BUY NOW' %></button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css for my homepage:

```
.home {
  background: image-url('laughter.jpg');
}

.banner {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You can use a higher z-index to control the stacking of elements.

Comment: please provide your codes.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Your nav and content will have their own height attributes, but you place your background image in a div that's the wrapper of those two. Then you can set any opacity level you want on your content containers.

```css
.wrapper {
  width:1024px;
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_1280.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:50% 50%;
}
.nav, .content {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.nav {
  height:50px;
}

.content {
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav"> Nav </div>
  <div class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae sapien dapibus, sodales ex vitae, fringilla sapien. Sed varius pulvinar sem a eleifend. Aliquam id enim et mauris efficitur porta. Pellentesque mattis turpis non sollicitudin volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur blandit lectus ut eleifend interdum. Nulla eu rhoncus metus, at facilisis dolor. Suspendisse a quam ut sapien pulvinar volutpat. Donec at elit ligula. Nunc condimentum blandit consectetur. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should probably have given some more information. I want the content and the navbar to have the same background image, but make the content naturally be arranged under the navbar.

Comment: Hi @HansMartinHanken - I've updated my code for an example of a way to do it. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mattius, this makes a lot of sense. I'm just trying to figure out how to do this when having more than one page on a website without adding the navbar to each page individually. Not sure if you are familiar with Rails, but a lot of frameworks and CMS solutions uses similar ways of pulling in the page content after the navigation for example. In ROR it's via <%= yield %>. Please let me know if you don't understand...